# How do I add text at the end of this PHP script

Tags: php

Here is the script normally. It saves data to a file.

```
       <?php
if (isset($_GET['field'])) {
$file = 'data.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);

// Append a new line to the file
$current .= "\n".$_GET['field'];

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
?>
```

But I want it to add (added by a user) at the end of what is sent. I have tried this:

```
     <?php
if (isset($_GET['field'])) {
$file = 'data.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);

// Append a new line to the file
$current .= "\n".$_GET['field'] + "(added by a user)";

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work. How do I do this?

Comment: concatenation in PHP is `.` not `+`, `$_GET['field'] + "(added by a user)";`

Comment: `$current .= "\n".$_GET['field'] . "(added by a user)";`

Comment: Isn't `$_GET['field']` coming from the user? Again you can use the `append` flag rather then reading the file to memory, concatenating, and rewriting.

Comment: Thank you so much!